# encoding binary to DNA sequence inC#

Tags: c#, dna-sequence

I would like to encode binary sequence to DNA sequence by truth table :
`00=A
01=C
10=G
11=T`
 For example:``` 11000110=``TACG ```By using C#, My issue, is the DNA sequence is not correctly converted. Does someone can help me PLEASE ?

the code i write is this :

```
 string ds = Convert.ToString(result , 2);

                       ;
                       int l = ds.Length;
                       for (int dd= 0; dd < l; dd = dd + 2)
                       {

                           if (ds.Contains("00"))
                           {
                               ds = ds.Replace("00", "A");

                           }
                           if (ds.Contains("01"))
                           {
                               ds = ds.Replace("01", "C");

                           }
                            if (ds.Contains("10"))
                           {
                               ds = ds.Replace("10", "G");
                           }
                           else
                           {
                           ds = ds.Replace("11", "T");
                           }
                       }
                       listBox7.Items.Add(ds);
```

Comment: Can you provide some code ?

Comment: this is my code

Comment: Are all values other than 00, 01, 10 and 11 invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proposal. In fact, there are thousands of possible solutions.

```
    string binary = "011001010101000100101";
    var codes = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"00", "A"},
        {"01", "C"},
        {"10", "G"},
        {"11", "T"}
    };

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i + 1 < binary.Length; i = i + 2) {
        var localCode = string.Format("{0}{1}", binary[i], binary[i+1]);
        string buffer;
        var output = codes.TryGetValue(localCode, out buffer) ? buffer : string.Empty;
        builder.Append(output);
    }

    string result = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: If it was useful, don’t hestitate to upvote my answer.

Comment: sorry but how can i do this i am new here !!

Comment: You can upvote once you have 15 rep or more. If you accept the answer I just posted you can upvote this one. And mine :P

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
var dna = DNA("11000110");
```

---

```
string DNA(string input)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "11", "T" }, { "00", "A" }, 
                                                  { "01", "C" }, { "10", "G" } };
    int inx = 0;

    return string.Concat(input.GroupBy(x => inx++ / 2).Select(g => dict[string.Concat(g)]));
}
```

Result: dna = `TACG`